# rxjs debouncetime not working when source stream is `of`

Tags: rxjs, rxjs7

Considering the following setup

```
of('x')
   .pipe(
     startWith('y'),
     debounceTime(1000))
.subscribe(console.log);
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vakoot-9jsbda?devtoolsheight=50&file=index.ts)

It prints without any delay the valye 'x'

Doing the same thing as follows

```
const clicks = fromEvent(document, 'click');
clicks
    .pipe(
       map(() => 'x'),
       startWith('y'),
       debounceTime(1000)
)
.subscribe(console.log);
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vakoot-9jsbda?devtoolsheight=50&file=index.ts)

I do get that delay for the inital value `y` and also later for each click. So the question is, why do I not get any delay when using `of`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`of()` completes immediately after emitting its only value. In this case, `debounceTime()` does not wait, but also emits right away. From the docs:

> If the completing event happens during dueTime the last cached notification is emitted before the completion event is forwarded to the output observable

`fromEvent()` does not complete, so the behavior is as you would expect.

Comment: It makes me wonder, how should you rewrite my first code example to overcome this issue?

Comment: You could create an observable that emits once, but does not complete, like this: `const obs$ = new Observable((subscriber) => subscriber.next('x'));`